# Explicitly Embedding $\mathbb{RP}^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

A version of the Whitney embedding theorem guarantees an embedding $\mathbb{RP}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^6$; I would like to find it explicitly. I am able to find constructions of the Whitney embedding $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$, but none for higher dimensional projective spaces.

I surmised that I might be able to find a map $S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^3$ that is an immersion respecting the quotient $S^3 \to \mathbb{RP}^3$, but I'm not sure if any of my candidate maps are, in fact, immersions. How would one go about with such a construction?